# how to get weeklytotal and yesterday record in mysql in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Everyone i am trying to implement query to get weekly and yesterday data in same table,
dummy output i have shared below, if yesterday not exist as per employee_id it should we showing 0 also as per my table week start from monday and end at sunday.please help me out how to query this get weekly_total and yesterday record and one table.

**Table name-dailydata-**

**Sample data**

| employee_id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2022-04-25 | 10 |
| 20 | 2022-04-26 | 20 |
| 20 | 2022-04-27 | 20 |
| 20 | 2022-04-28 | 10 |
| 20 | 2022-04-29 | 20 |
| 20 | 2022-04-30 | 30 |
| 20 | 2022-04-31 | 40 |
| 20 | 2022-05-01 | 50 |
| 40 | 2022-04-26 | 20 |

**expected output**

| employee_id | weekly_total | yesterday_record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 200 | 40 |
| 40 | 20 | 0 |

**mysql query to get weekly data**

```
select employee_id,sum(total) as week_total from dailydata where date between '2022-04-25' and '2022-05-01'
```

Comment: Please provide the entire data schema (table definitions etc.) including the sample data. You can use this site: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: i have already given

Comment: Please provide some sample text data which can align with your expert result. What is `yesterday_record` logic?

Comment: i have added sample data

Comment: Please note that there is no 31st of April ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function to make it.

We might add non-aggregate columns in the group by when we are using aggregate functions.

```
select employee_id,
       SUM(total) as week_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF('2022-05-01',date) = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) yesterday_record   
from dailydata t1
where date between '2022-04-25' and '2022-05-01'
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case in the query to get yesterdays data, as long as the where does not exclude it, which is the case in the second query.
Once you have understood the principal you can define the date range so that it is calculated dynamically when you run the script if what you want is to see yesterday's figure and the last 7 days total.
You can also get yesterday using `SUBDATE(NOW(),1)` which is shorter.

```
select 
  employee_id,
  sum(total) as week_total ,
  sum(case when date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
          then total else 0 end as yesterday
from dailydata 
where date between 
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
```

```
select 
  employee_id,
  sum(total) as week_total ,
  sum(case when date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
          then total else 0 end as yesterday
from dailydata 
where date between '2022-04-25' and '2022-05-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Start of this week:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

End of this week:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 6)
```

Yesterday:

```
select GETDATE() -1
```

Your query:

```
select 
    employee_id,
    sum(total) as week_total, 
    (select sum(total) as week_total 
     from dailydata b 
     where [date] = convert(date, getdate() -1 ) 
       and a.employee_id = b.employee_id) as yesterday_record 
from 
    dailydata a 
where 
    [date] between dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0) and dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 6)
group by 
    employee_id
```

Comment: This query will not be executed due to incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you, You just need to use the aggregate function in the case of IFNULL.

DBFiddle URL: [Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e6662e3832b65cdb60dec2915dc1e2e)

For the start of the week

```
SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), weekday(CURDATE())); --Start of week
```

For the end of the week

```
SELECT DATE(CURDATE() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY); --End of week
```

Hereby SQL query for getting employe wise total and yesterday total. If yesterday's total doesn't exist so for that Have used IFNULL. Just used SUBDATE for getting the start and end of the week date by passing current date.

```
SELECT employee_id, 
IFNULL(SUM(total),0) AS total,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE date WHEN subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN total ELSE 0 END),0) AS yesterday_total
FROM dailydata
WHERE date BETWEEN 
SUBDATE(CURDATE(), weekday(CURDATE())) AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY)
GROUP BY employee_id
```